# Opening .odf requires admin rights?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, openoffice

One of our users and one of her colleagues is getting an error when opening an ODF file (open office word), something about XML and then a second error message asking to repair the file (which does not work). It appears as though the file is corrupt. She has full control, just like the administrator. She could though open the file under her account on one of our spare laptops,

I noticed that I can open the same file on the same computer using the administrator account, as well as when I run Word as administrator, with no message dialogs whatsoever. I have not checked with multiple files but I don't believe the file to be the issue considering it could be opened as administrator without problems. I suspect the "plugin" that allows opening of ODF files (part of Office SP1 if I'm not mistaken) or Office itself.

We're not going to provide admin rights, obviously, so does anyone know what this could be, or provide a solution?

Comment: Have you checked the file's ACL gives the user read access?

Comment: She has full control, just like the administrator. I suspect the problem lies with the "plugin" that allows opening of ODF files (part of Office SP1 if I'm not mistaken) or Office itself. Just not sure how to resolve it

Comment: You need to eliminate possibilities: is it just this one file? Is it just this one user?

Comment: Apparently one of her colleagues had the same issue, and I have not checked with multiple files but I don't believe the file to be a problem considering it could be opened as administrator without problems. Now that you mention it though, she could open the file under her account on one of our spare laptops, so I'm not sure what's up with that